# Mcomix to view cbr comix file

Tags: xubuntu

when I run "mcomix" to open e read a .cbr file I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/usr/bin/mcomix", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('mcomix==1.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'mcomix')()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mcomix/run.py", line 206, in run
assert PIL.Image.VERSION >= '1.1.5' 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'VERSION'
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks